How to get Pyth dependency to use V1 Solana SDK?
I have built a project using Anchor + V1 Solana SDK. I am trying to add Pyth dependency to my project.
https://crates.io/crates/pyth-solana-receiver-sdk/0.3.2
How to reproduce
avm use 0.29.0
rustup override set 1.75 
anchor init test_project

add the example to test_project
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use pyth_solana_receiver_sdk::price_update::{get_feed_id_from_hex, PriceUpdateV2};

declare_id!("2e5gZD3suxgJgkCg4pkoogxDKszy1SAwokz8mNeZUj4M");

pub const MAXIMUM_AGE: u64 = 60; // One minute
pub const FEED_ID: &str = "0xef0d8b6fda2ceba41da15d4095d1da392a0d2f8ed0c6c7bc0f4cfac8c280b56d"; // SOL/USD price feed id from https://pyth.network/developers/price-feed-ids

#[program]
pub mod my_first_pyth_app {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let price_update = &mut ctx.accounts.price_update;
        let price = price_update.get_price_no_older_than(
            &Clock::get()?,
            MAXIMUM_AGE,
            &get_feed_id_from_hex(FEED_ID)?,
        )?;
        /// Do something with the price
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub price_update: Account<'info, PriceUpdateV2>,
    // Add more accounts here
}

cargo dependencies
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
solana-program = "1.18"
pyth-solana-receiver-sdk = "0.3.2"

when I do cargo update it seems to break anchor build - upon inspecing the cargo.lock file there are 2 Solana program dependencies - 1.18 and 2.1

This one's a bit annoying, pyth-solana-receiver-sdk has a transitive dependency on pythnet-sdk v2. That crate upgraded to solana-program v2 without a major version update, which then means that you'll get both major versions of solana-program on a fresh build.
If you want to make sure you only get one version of solana-program, you can pin pythnet-sdk to v2.1. This worked for me -- try updating your Cargo.toml to the following:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
solana-program = "1.18"
pyth-solana-receiver-sdk = "0.3.2"
pythnet-sdk = "~2.1"
borsh = "~1.2"

A lower version of Borsh was also needed due to https://github.com/near/borsh-rs/issues/319

To use the V1 Solana SDK with Pyth in your Anchor project, you need to adjust your dependencies to ensure compatibility. Here’s a step-by-step guide to help you resolve the version conflict:
1.Set Up Your Project Environment:
avm use 0.29.0  
rustup override set 1.75  
anchor init test_project  

2.Add Dependencies:
Open your Cargo.toml file and add the dependencies as follows:
[dependencies]  
anchor-lang = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["anchor-spl"] }  
solana-program = "=1.18"  
pyth-solana-receiver-sdk = "0.3.2"  

By setting solana-program = "=1.18", you ensure that both Anchor and Pyth use the same version.
3.Implement Your Code:
Add the example code to your lib.rs or main.rs file:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;  
use pyth_solana_receiver_sdk::price_update::{get_feed_id_from_hex, PriceUpdateV2};  

declare_id!("2e5gZD3suxgJgkCg4pkoogxDKszy1SAwokz8mNeZUj4M");  

pub const MAXIMUM_AGE: u64 = 60; // One minute  
pub const FEED_ID: &str = "0xef0d8b6fda2ceba41da15d4095d1da392a0d2f8ed0c6c7bc0f4cfac8c280b56d";   

#[program]  
pub mod my_first_pyth_app {  
    use super::*;  

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {  
        let price_update = &ctx.accounts.price_update;  
        let price = price_update.get_price_no_older_than(  
            &Clock::get()?,  
            MAXIMUM_AGE,  
            &get_feed_id_from_hex(FEED_ID)?,  
        )?;  
        // Do something with the price  
        Ok(())  
    }  
}  

#[derive(Accounts)]  
pub struct Initialize<'info> {  
    #[account(mut)]  
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,  
    pub price_update: Account<'info, PriceUpdateV2>,  
    // Add more accounts here  
}  

4.Update Dependencies:
Run cargo update to update your dependencies.
5.Build Your Project:
Use anchor build to build your project and ensure that there are no errors.
By ensuring the Solana SDK dependency is explicitly set to version 1.18, you resolve the version conflicts between Anchor, Solana, and Pyth. This setup should allow you to use Pyth with the V1 Solana SDK seamlessly.

Please avoid posting what looks like LLM output. In this case, the solution doesn't work.
